# File Uploader Control showing Has File False

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using File Upload Control inside Update Panel with setting trigger

```
<Triggers>
            <ajax:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
            </Triggers>
```

but still now it is showing Has File Property to false.

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

FileUpload control does not work with UpdatePanel because It needs full postback not partial postback. You always get null when you access file.

Comment: then how can i use file upload control.

Comment: if i put file upload control outside the update panel but Upload button inside the Update Panel then it will work ?

Answer (score 1):

File upload control will not work with Update panel. If you are using telerik, then try asynchronous Rad Upload control with Update panel.. Or Remove Upload Panel & work with File Upload Control.

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload1.HasFile will have false value if you are trying to upload file size of zero. so make sure (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0),
remember
if file size is zero then FileUpload1 will contain file name, file type,file size etc but hasfile will be false.
Happy coding..